# layoyt-sw1280dp

Tags: android, android-layout

Доброго времени суток. Есть приложение работающие под одно устройство, в плане верстки (600*1024). Появилась необходимость добавить верстку еще одно устройство (720*1280). Ничего сложного, казалось бы. Но добавление соответствующих разметок не дало результатов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите дерево каталогов ресурсов (всех)

Answer (score 0):

В директории `res` создайте директорию `layout-large` это для `600x1024`, также создайте директорию `layout-xlarge` это уже для `720x1280` и помещайте туда нужные разметки, а затем задавайте им пропорции в соответствии с этим расширением.

Comment: так тоже не работает. Более того после переноса в эту папку макета ориентация меняется на альбомную

Answer (score 0):

layoyt-sw1280dp

простая арифметика
sw - значит минимальная сторона
( 1280dp / 160 ) * 2,54 =  20,32см. разметка с этой папки будет использована для устройств у которых минимальная сторона дисплея равна 20.32см. думаю ваша проблема в том что вы неправильно создали название папки

Comment: Дело в том,что это планшеты на 7", и тот и тот

Comment: такой вариант рассматривали:  сделать проверку на разрешение монитора, используя if-else делать setContentView(R.layout.content1280); или setContentView(R.layout.content1024);

Comment: так работает. Но как быть с ресурсами типа `style` и `dimens`